# Why can't I search successfully for [chronology] questions?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

When I search for the [chronology](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology) tag using the searchbox (by typing `[chronology]`) or click on the [chronology](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology) tag link, it tells me there are `0 questions tagged chronology` and

> You are on the FAQ tab. There are no frequently asked questions at the moment. Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?

Yet, searching for [chronology](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=chronology) without the `[]` tag marker brings up a load of questions, some of which are tagged [chronology](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology).

Comment: I get 4 research results when searching for `[chronology]`.  Make sure you click on the `newest` or `votes` tab to see these.  There are no `frequent` or `unanswered` results.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Ah, I see, thanks. Then I should probably change the question to why the tag gets you to the FAQ section rather than a more general one.

Comment: Most of the time it remembers which tab you used last and shows that.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Ok, now I feel really stupid ...

Answer (score 5):

The search results have a number of "tabs".  In the case of `[chronology]` you need to click on `newest` or `votes` to see 4 hits, `frequent` and `unanswered` currently have no hits.  By default, the system remembers which tab you looked at last time you did a search, so the first list shown to you has a good chance of being one of the tabs with a small number of matches.